# Load Balanced SFTP Server

Tags: ftp, load-balancing, azure, sftp, web-farm

we have 2 Load Balanced web servers on Azure and I am trying to set up a load balanced SFTP connection for my client.

I have tried doing this using a load balanced end-point on azure for SFTP but the FTP connection only connects and transfers files to 1 server.

I wanted to know whether there is a way in which I can synchronise the SFTP connection for my client on both the servers.

Any idea of how I can achieve this task?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, at least to me. You talk about SFTP but then you say the "FTP connection". But SFTP and FTP are not even related to each other. Please clarify. What kind of SFTP (or FTP) server are you using, and how? What are you really trying to accomplish? Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to load balance SFTP? loadbalancing sftp doesnt really make sense as you get the exact problem you described, two different servers with different files, you want a networked drive really

Answer (score 2):

That's not how load balancing works.
A load balancer distributes incoming connections towards the server behind it to ensure the minimum amount of work for each one of them.
For example: let's say that there are 10 incoming connections, and you have 3 load-balanced servers; your load balancer will send 3 connections to the first server, 3 connections to the second server, and 4 connections to the third server.

So what you're talking about is NOT load balancing. What you really need to do is to create a shared storage area (a NAS, a DFS, ...) to be used as data repository for both your SFTP servers. If you do so, then all your files will be there, regardless of which specific SFTP server serves your incoming connection.